# Problems with [NSDate date] and the leap year

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate

On the leap year, `[NSDate date]` returns `2012-03-01 HH:MM:SS +TTTT`.

On stackoverflow I've often seen posts where today's date is retrieved by simply calling `[NSDate date]`.  The problem is that on the leap year this is not going to return the correct date.  Now I understand that the leap year is actually a function of a calendrical system so it makes sense that `NSDate` wouldn't recognize the leap year (or daylight savings time for that matter).  However, this has the potential to wreck havoc in code - for example:

say you assign a file modification date by doing:

```
// assume today's date is 2012-02-29 10:00:00 +0000
NSDate *fileModificationDate = [NSDate date];    // 2012-03-01 10:00:00 +0000 is returned
```

Then at some point in the future you do a comparison to see when the file was last modified:

```
// assume it's the next day at 9 AM, ie 2012-03-01 09:00 +0000
NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastModification = [fileModificationDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

The returned `timeSinceLasModification` will be positive, signifying a time in the future which makes no sense!

My questions is: is it actually bad practice to use `[NSDate date]` to get the current date?  Am I missing something important here?

Sorry for the long winded question...

Comment: No-repro. Printing `[NSDate date]` via `NSLog` has shown 2/29 for me all day long. What's your time zone? How are you displaying the date?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know where you got the idea that `NSDate` doesn't support leap day, but it's absolutely wrong. I believe you're getting confused because right now in GMT, the date string is `2012-03-01 03:42:07 +0000`. This is *correct*. In GMT, it's already March 1st. But if you ask for the date in the current locale (e.g. `[[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]`) you'll get a correct value of leap day. For me in PST, it's

> Wednesday, February 29, 2012 7:42:46 PM Pacific Standard Time

Note that `NSDate` itself is locale-unaware. The only change I made was asking it to return the string representation using the current locale instead of using GMT. I could take that same date object and ask for EST and it would give me the correct string for that time zone as well.

Comment: Wow... I feel absolutely ridiculous for not picking up on that!  Thank you for the answer Kevin, you are completely right!  So does NSDate actually account for things such as daylight savings time?... I could have swore I read something about it not doing so

Comment: Technically/strictly/pedantically (but I believe this reinforces your point) `NSDate` _doesn't_ "support" leap day -- that's a function of the calendar/locale. `NSDate` is just a point in time; it's up to the calendrical system to provide a label or description for it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I think what Kevin was saying is that since we are in PST that in GMT time it's actually March 1st - if it was earlier in the day and I had called `[NSDate date]` it would have returned Feb 29th at some time.

Comment: @Jake: I was agreeing with Kevin, though I may have put it poorly. This question comes up on SO a lot and I've answered it myself before.

Comment: @JakeV: `NSDate` itself is, fundamentally, just an offset in seconds from the reference date (Jan 1 2001). As Josh said, it's up to the calendar to translate that into year/month/day/etc, including DST and leap day.